# setTimeout on if else statement

Tags: javascript, html, function, animation, settimeout

I'm making a first-time website and wanted to have a 0-100% progress bar which has a delay of a few seconds to first fade in at the start (which I can do in CSS), but the progress bar script doesn't seem to delay when I put the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="loading">
    <div class="percent">100%</div>
    <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var percent = document.querySelector(".percent");
var progress = document.querySelector(".progress");
var count = 1;
var per = 1;
var loading = setInterval(animate, 25);

setTimeout(animate, 2000);

function animate() {
  if (count == 100 && per == 100) {
    clearInterval(loading);
  } else {
    per = per + 1;
    count = count + 1;
    progress.style.width = per + "px";
    percent.textContent = count + "%";
  }
}
```

I've tried this but this doesn't even animate the progression bar:

```
setTimeout(function animate() {
  if (count == 100 && per == 100) {
    clearInterval(loading);
  } else {
    per = per + 1;
    count = count + 1;
    progress.style.width = per + "px";
    percent.textContent = count + "%";
  }
}, 2000);
```

I've also tried putting the setTimeout in a var called timeInMilliseconds set to 2000 and putting that instead of a time but that didn't work.

Apologies if the answer is really obvious, this is all new and I've been leeching off of tutorials trying to learn as much as I can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code looks OK to me (other than the `setTimeout`, just the `setInterval` should do as you want) - are you sure it is running after the relevant DOM elements exist? Are there any errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close!

All the relevant action is happening here:

```
var loading = setInterval(animate, 25);

setTimeout(animate, 2000);
```

What's happening is this: as soon as `var loading = setInterval(animate, 24);` is evaluated, the browser starts calling your `animate` function every 24ms. Then, 2 seconds later, it calls `animate` *again* (however, this time it doesn't do anything new, since `count` and `per` are still equal to `100`).

Here's a fix, step by step:

1. We know that we want to do something after a 2 second delay. Let's generalize what you have at the moment:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  // we want to start our animation loop here
}, 2000);
```

2. What do we want to do after 2 seconds? That is, what goes in the body of the function we passed to `setTimeout`? It's the looping logic you have already written above:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  loading = setInterval(animate, 25);
}, 2000);
```

To summarize, this fragment now waits for 2 seconds, then starts looping your `animate` function.

One last thing!
Even though `loading` isn't *assigned* until inside of the timeout, we still need to *declare* it in the global scope (so `animate` can have access to it).
So our revisions look like this:

```
var percent = document.querySelector(".percent");
var progress = document.querySelector(".progress");
var count = 1;
var per = 1;
var loading; // <- Still declared in the global scope

setTimeout(() => {
  loading = setInterval(animate, 25);
}, 2000);

function animate() {
  if (count == 100 && per == 100) {
    clearInterval(loading);
  } else {
    per = per + 1;
    count = count + 1;
    progress.style.width = per + "px";
    percent.textContent = count + "%";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help out, it worked like a charm!

Comment: Happy to help! Keep it up, my friend!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a function that will call `setInterval` after 2 seconds. From there you call `setInterval` and assign `loading` to the interval. The `loading` variable is global so `animate` can access it too.

Then with the `setTimeout` function call the function that starts the animation to set the delay.

```js
var percent = document.querySelector(".percent");
var progress = document.querySelector(".progress");
var count = 1;
var per = 1;
var loading;

setTimeout(startAnimation, 2000);

function startAnimation() {
  loading = setInterval(animate, 25);
}

function animate() {
  if (count == 100 && per == 100) {
    clearInterval(loading);
  } else {
    per = per + 1;
    count = count + 1;
    progress.style.width = per + "px";
    percent.textContent = count + "%";
  }
}
```

```css
.progress {
  height: 10px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: green;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
    <div class="percent">0%</div>
    <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```